# mysql insert append string on field if string not already exists

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'words' like this:

```
id      column1         column2        lang

1       word1           category1       en
```

The id column is UNIQUE primary key and column1 can't be unique because some words can be same in other langage (lang)

Each word can have one or many categories in column2 ex: category1,category2 ... etc.

First i check if the word exist in that langage and if exist and I save the id

PHP

```
$id = 1;
$word = 'word1';
$category = 'category2';
$lang = 'en';


INSERT INTO words (id , column1, column2, lang)
VALUES ($id, '$word', '$category', '$lang')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id = $id,
column1 = '$word',
column2 = CONCAT(column2, ',$category'),
lang = '$lang'
```

That working good if $category not yet in column2 but if exist column 2 become: category1,category2,category2 ... etc ...

What I need is each category only be once in column2 ex: `category1,category2` **and not** `category1,category2,category2` **OR** `category2,category1,category2`

Comment: You should use one row per word-category-pair. Never ever store more than one piece of data in one field in a database. It will also solve your problem, because then you can easily check if a word-category-pair already exists before you insert it.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'll try (but I will need a lot of changes :( )

Comment: Trust me, it is worth it, for example just suppose you want to find all words that belong to a certain category...that is so much easier and faster, if the categories for your word are not in a list. I suggest you read about database normalisation to find out more about this topic.